# Referencing a macro variable created by a prompt SAS EG

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I created a prompt in SAS EG that takes a text input and creates the macro variable called 'variableName'.

I am trying to reference this macro variable like so:

```
proc sql;
create table MyTable as
   select * from Source_Table as a
   where a.field = &variableName ;
```

This gives me an error that says: "Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a name, a quoted string, a numeric constant, a datetime constant, a missing value, BTRIM, INPUT, PUT, SUBSTRING, USER."

I have also tried enclosing &variableName in single and double quotes but when I do that I just don't get any results.

I am able to reference the prompt when I use query builder and filter data based on the prompt, but I am trying to use the prompt's value in calculated expressions, etc. and in queries I write without query builder. How can i reference the variable I created in the prompt??

Edit: code with a value that the macro variable would have

```
proc sql;
create table MyTable as
    select * from Source_Table as a
    where a.field = 'NAME OF PERSON';
```

When I run that, I get the results I want.

Answer (score 0):

It needs to resolve to valid SAS code. Assuming &variableName is a string, then it would be something like:

```
proc sql;
create table MyTable as
   select * from Source_Table as a
   where a.field = "&variableName." ;
```

If this isn't working, please show a query that does work with the same value as the macro variable would have. And then we can suggest how to change your code.

Edit: based on your comment you do not have the prompt connected to your query. Right click the query and link the prompt to your query and it will run before the query to provide the value.

Comment: Yes, &variableName is a string. I tried that, but the prompt does not pop up for me to select a value, and then the query runs and returns no results. I will edit my question and add a query with what the macro variable would have.

Comment: Did you set the prompt to be called on that query? You need to right click it and connect it somehow, but I dont recall right now.

Comment: Ah, I did not know I had to do that. I did that and it seems to be working now! Thank you so much.

Comment: Now when I use it, it tells me that the value of my variable "is not valid in the context in which it is used" do you know what that might mean?

Comment: Nope. Check what the value resolves to using `%PUT &variableName.;`. But if you selected a data set or variable name rather than text that's probably why. If you're still having issues, post a new question and include a screenshot of your prompt.

Comment: It looks like I had to add single quotes around my variable value. I am not sure why but when my variable was stored as NAME it gave me errors whereas if it was stored as 'NAME' it worked fine.Thanks again! `%put &variableName` helped me find this.

Comment: Are you using quotes within the macro variable? otherwise that doesn't make sense. Macro variables ONLY resolve within double quotes.

Comment: The macro variable pulls from a dynamic list which contains all text values. When i did `%put &variableName` it returned: NAME. This returned nothing when i ran my create table query. I researched and defined a new variable to be `%let newVar =%unquote(%str(%'&variableName%'));` This returned 'NAME' and worked for me in my queries that referenced `&newVar`